# MongoDB performance problem

Tags: performance, optimization, mongodb, php, query-performance

I have a MongoDB for storing result like this

```
{_id, type, imei, lat, lng, spd, dir, time}
{_id, type, imei, lac, cid, time}
```

If `type` is `f` first one is used and if it is `l` second one is used.

Here is the indexes:

```
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 340358704,
    "imei_1" : 614508160,
    "type_1" : 183616608,
    "type_1_imei_1" : 349793808
},
```

Collection has about 10 million documents. I have many queries on `type` and `imei`, and for now only types of `f` are used in applications.

This is a line from log file

```
Sun Aug 31 19:14:39.402 [conn782250] query xxyyxx.locs query: { $query: { $and: [ { imei: "359710042581612" }, { type: "f" } ] }, $orderby: { time: -1 } } ntoreturn:1 ntoskip:0 nscanned:140455 scanAndOrder:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields: 59 locks(micros) r:38456361 nreturned:1 reslen:159 19727ms
```

This took about 20 seconds, too much.

I need to optimize my collection more. This is used in a web application and sometimes queries like this are performed for 10 `imei`s, taking about 200 seconds, which may lead to a timeout. This is performed async (ajax) but still too much waiting time.

Any help from experts here is more than welcome.

Also, if you think I missed anything, please do request more information.

Thanks in advance

BTW, I'm using PHP for web part (Laravel framework and https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB)

EDIT: Here is the `explain` (REMOVED)

EDIT2: After creating better indexes:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> use gpstracker
switched to db gpstracker
> db.locs.stats()
{
    "ns" : "gpstracker.locs",
    "count" : 10137188,
    "size" : 1400944384,
    "avgObjSize" : 138.19852053646434,
    "storageSize" : 1580060672,
    "numExtents" : 19,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 415145984,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 826806176,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 359997456,
        "type_1_imei_1_time_-1" : 466808720
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.locs.find({ $and: [ { imei: "359710042581612" }, { type: "f" } ] }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor type_1_imei_1_time_-1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 150158,
    "nscannedObjects" : 150158,
    "nscanned" : 150158,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 150158,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 150158,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 329,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 128173,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "type" : [
            [
                "f",
                "f"
            ]
        ],
        "imei" : [
            [
                "359710042581612",
                "359710042581612"
            ]
        ],
        "time" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "CDSX001:27017"
}
```

Comment: If all your documents have a `type` value of `f`, it isn't useful to include in the index. An index only helps with criteria that is *selective* and helps limit results. If your typical query is on `imei` ordered by time (descending), I would add an index on `{ imei: 1, time: -1}`. Also, you do not need `$and` in your example query; this is implicit in a default query.  What version of MongoDB are you using?  Have you tried using [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/) to look at the query plan?

Comment: Also, you don't need to have an index on both `type:1` and `{ type: 1, imei:1 }` as per your index list. A compound index on `{type:1, imei:1}` can be also be used to satisfy queries on `type:1` (or more generically, any proper subset of keys that match the order of a compound index from left to right).

Comment: Good points on indexes, thanks. So it is safe to removed indexes om `imei` and `type` (but not the combined one). I only _use_ `type`s of `f`, but I store `type`s of `l` too. They will be used later. I will try adding index on `time` too, and see the results.

Comment: And about `$and`, this is not a query by me. It is generated by framework. May this have any performance impacts? If it has, I will look into using my own queries.

Comment: Can you execute an explain on your query and post the results? Regarding indexes This index"type_1" is covered by "type_1_imei_1" and can be safely removed.

Comment: @Antonis I have added `explain` to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is using the index to fetch the results but needs to sort them afterwards which is an expensive operation.

"scanAndOrder" : true, scanAndOrder is a boolean that is true when the query cannot use the order of documents in the index for returning sorted results: MongoDB must sort the documents after it receives the documents from a cursor.

The solution is to apply an index on {imei:1, type:1, time:-1} or {type:1, imei:1, time:-1} (the imei,type order on the index depends on imei and type selectivity)

Comment: After the proposed index creation remove type_1_imei_1. Plus remove if you choose {imei:1, type:1, time:-1} index imei_1 or if you choose {imei:1, type:1, time:-1} index type_1 since they are covered from the new index.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And I learned more on indexes. Now my AJAX request to server which executes about 20 queries like mentioned only takes 500 ms, very good. BTW, I think I will move documents of type `l` to a new collection. They have no use for now and are only decreasing performance. Thanks again! I also added new explain and index to question.